# SSRS Conversion from Access Query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have reports that are currently running from inside a macro on an Access database that we want to convert to SSRS reports.

I want to convert the Access query into a Shared Dataset that these reports can share as there are two parameters I would like to pass into this Shared Dataset, but I am having an issue getting this to work.

```
SELECT * FROM FROM ReportLog WHERE ClientName = [ClientNameParameter] AND 
DateEntered BETWEEN getstartdatedaily() AND DATE() - 1
ORDER BY DateEntered;
```

The above query is what I want to put into the Shared Dateset, but for each report, I would pass into the query the Client Name (I do not want the report to prompt the user for this) and getStartDateDaily is a function inside Access that I am not sure how to convert this to something SSRS can use.  Below is the code that runs the function, as I am not sure how to convert this to a parameter / function that the SSRS Report can use.

```
Public Function getStartDateDaily() As Date
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    If Weekday(Date) = 2 Then
        startDate = Date - 3
    Else
        startDate = Date - 1
    End If
    getStartDateDaily = startDate
End Function
```

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Northwind metaphor example

```
Use Northwind
Go

Select * from
(

SELECT [OrderID]
      ,[CustomerID]
      ,[EmployeeID]
      ,[OrderDate]
      ,[RequiredDate]
      ,[ShippedDate]
      ,[ShipVia]
      ,[Freight]
      ,[ShipName]
      ,[ShipAddress]
      ,[ShipCity]
      ,[ShipRegion]
      ,[ShipPostalCode]
      ,[ShipCountry]
      ,DATEPART(dw,[OrderDate]) as MyDATEPART
      , StartDateDaily =
      CASE
      WHEN DATEPART(dw,[OrderDate]) = 2 THEN DATEADD(d, -3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)--Date - 3
        ELSE DATEADD(d, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)  -- Date - 1
      END
  FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Orders]
) as derived1

Where OrderDate between StartDateDaily and  DATEADD(d, - 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

The above works.

My guess at yours: (hint, temporarily comment out the where clause below to see the computed values (MyDATEPART and StartDateDaily ) of the equation and tweak those if necessary)

```
Select * from
(

SELECT *
      ,DATEPART(dw,DateEntered) as MyDATEPART
      , StartDateDaily =
      CASE
      WHEN DATEPART(dw,DateEntered) = 2 THEN DATEADD(d, -3, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
        ELSE DATEADD(d, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
      END
  FROM ReportLog
) as derived1

Where DateEntered between StartDateDaily and  DATEADD(d, - 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: This works great for the function.  Greatly appreciate the help.  I cant do an "up" arrow though as I have less than 15 points, but helped greatly.  Thank you so much

Comment: if you use getStartDateDaily in many places, you can encapsulate it in a User Defined (Scalar) Function.    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Scalar Functions

Comment: Note, you should not use "select *" in production code.  Put in all/any/necessary column names in your queries.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the scalar functions, but unfortunately, we can't add anything to the database itself for this.  Also: the Select * was simply me removing tons of columns to make the code more readable.

Comment: Ok  I was talking about "my" "select *" statements.  (for me, you and future readers).  Carry on !!